# When can clustering be used for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, hierarchical-clustering

Can a clustering method be used for dimensionality reduction?

I though the answer would be that the cluster numbers can act as the synthetic reduced dimension -- but the other day a friend had a more sophisticated idea that I didn't totally understand.

Comment: Hierarchical CA, for example, can be performed to cluster variables (dimensions). Highly correlated variables can be seen as duplicates of each other.

Comment: We aren't going to be able to explain an idea to you when we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

"Reducing" dimensionality by mapping data points to cluster numbers is a *bad* idea. You lose almost all the information. There is no meaning to the distances in the resulting "space". You can simply treat every cluster as a different set, that is all the information you retained (because cluster numbers are meaningless!)

Furthermore, **your clustering is probably not good, if you didn't fix such issues with your data before**. You have a catch-22 here. Don't rely on something for dimensionality reduction that itself suffers badly from dimensionality!

What you can do is to cluster dimensions instead of data points. This can help identify correlated attributes (and thus be used to "reduce dimensionality"). But there are straightforward, and much cleaner, methods for this than cluster analysis. Also, the problem of badly preprocessed data, outliers, etc. remains.

I'd suggest to not do this.